# Find most frequently accessed tables in SQL Server 2014 without VIEW SERVER STATE permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to use this query to get the most frequently accessed tables in a database:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS tname,
    SUM(ius.user_seeks + ius.user_scans + ius.user_lookups) AS accesses
FROM db_name.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius
INNER JOIN db_name.sys.tables t ON t.OBJECT_ID = ius.object_id
GROUP BY database_id, t.name
ORDER BY accesses DESC
```

But it fails with the error

```
Msg 300, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
```

Understandably, our backend hosting company doesn't want to give out the VIEW SERVER STATE permission to just any random intern. Is there a query (or a tool within SQL Server) that might achieve the same or similar results without needing this permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
SELECT t.name, range_scan_count+singleton_lookup_count AS accesses, * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(db_id(),NULL,NULL,NULL) os
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = os.object_id
ORDER BY accesses DESC
```

This should work with the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission (even if you don't have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission).

However, this query does not return the same thing as your query. See the differences here: http://web.archive.org/web/20180410202012/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/17/Seeking-Without-Indexes.aspx